# How can I delete my bluemix account id?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I will change my bluemix account. for that reason I want to delete (or disable ) IBM Account and Bluemix ID.  I cloud not find the function on Bluemix ACE Console.

Comment: Please contact IBM Bluemix support to get this resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deletion of accounts for IBM Bluemix requires to contact the support via the [support](http://support.ibmcloud.com/) website.

If you just want to "pause", then you could just delete existing services and apps.

Comment: Does this process close the IBM Cloud account *AND* delete the IBM ID?